# getExternalFilesDir(null) returns null

Tags: android

Once again, I've come up against a question which has been asked and answered before but in my implementation it is still not working.

I'm calling **getExternalFilesDir(null)** right at the very start of my main activity's **onCreate** method. It returns null every time, whether I run it in an AVD or on my phone (Samsung Galaxy Plus).

Yes, I have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` line in my **AndroidManifest.xml** and yes, I am checking the external storage state before I make the call and it is mounted.

Here are the first three lines inside my **onCreate()** method. Actually, it's just after the **super.onCreate()** and **setContentView()** calls.

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
File extFiles = getExternalFilesDir(null);
File locFiles = getFilesDir();
```

So, once these three lines have executed, these are the values for the variables:

```
state == "mounted"
extFiles == null
locFiles == "/data/data/com.mypackage.name/files"
```

Would anyone have any ideas as to why this might be?

**-----EDIT-----**

So I've tried another approach; Rather than using `getExternalFilesDir(null)`, I tried using `File basePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myAppName");`

This is not ideal and I know that the Android documentation says, and I agree with it, that you should rather use `getExternalFilesDir()`. Seeing as that's not working for me though I had to try something else. This time the function does return a valid File object so, after the above line, the path of basePath is **/mnt/sdcard/myAppName**. So far, so good. When I check with DDMS I can see that **/mnt/sdcard** exists but not **/mnt/sdcard/myAppName**. This is to be expected. So I call `boolean result = basePath.mkdirs();`

But this returns false and when I check on the file system I can confirm that the myAppName subfolder has not been created. When I create the folder manually through DDMS and put files in it, I can read those files from my application but I can't write anything in that folder.

Please help! I'm at my wit's end.

Comment: did you try with a specific type, such as `MUSIC` ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well and it also returns **null**.

Comment: 1) Clean/build project in Eclipse. 2) Full uninstall/reinstall of app. Does the same thing happen?

Comment: OK, I've just tried this and it doesn't help either. I've discovered another odd thing that might be related. I'll edit the original question to reflect this.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If this wasn't a typo when you posted your question, you'll probably hate yourself for this:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permissions.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

should be

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: You, sir, are my new best friend! I love you :-)  Good heavens, I've lost an entire day to this stupid typo.

As a matter of interest, minutes before your post I figured out that I didn't have the permission I requested but I couldn't figure out why. I added this line of code:
`(checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)`
which evaluates to **false**.

Is there any sort of output generated by the compiler to indicate when you have these kinds of errors in your manifest?

Comment: Not that I know of, in Android studio holding ctrl (cmd on mac) will underline a known permission when you mouse over it, but since you can request permissions for other apps that you might not have the code for, it would be hard to determine if a given permission is actually a typo or not

Answer (score 23):

This is from Android documentation:

> Returns the path of the directory holding application files on external storage. 
>   Returns null if external storage is not currently mounted so it could not ensure 
>   the path exists; you will need to call this method again when it is available.

The other option is you can check if External storage is available:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
File filesDir;

// Make sure it's available
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    // We can read and write the media
    filesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
} else {
    // Load another directory, probably local memory
    filesDir = getFilesDir();
}
```

Comment: I am checking that the media is mounted. If the function returns null because "external storage is not currently mounted", why then would the value of **state** in my code above be **"mounted"**?

Comment: ATTENTION! `getExternalFilesDir()` is available on API8+ and `getFilesDir()` is also NOT accessible on API19+ (KitKat). Proceed with caution :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I opened a FileOutputStream, then before I closed the FileOutputStream, I opened a FileInputStream to see what was already in the file.

I moved opening the FileInputStream to before the FileOutputStream is opened and that fixed my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Delete a line

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Switch a xml editor to "Android Manifest Permissions" with "Permission" tab in eclipse, and add a

```
uses-permission "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

with some clicks.

Then try running your application.

---

It seems eclipse (may depends on a defference of version or state or settings) can ignore some words described by direct xml in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

---

Thanks for an advise. You are right, my answer looked like to agree in small talk.

Comment: Sorry, that seems more like an "I have this problem too" comment than an answer to the question. If you are trying to answer the question, please consider re-wording your sentence or adding more details.